# Are all even graphs planar?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Recall that a graph is even when all its vertices are of even degree (number of incident edges; loops contributing two degrees each).

If not, is there any extra (set of) condition(s) needed to make an even graph planar (such as being simple, connected, etc.)

Surprisingly, I have difficulty looking up the answer, even though this seems like a simple and natural question to ask. Regrettably, I don't know enough about graph theory to figure it out by myself.

Comment: Any full graph with odd number of vertices would be even, but I doubt that many of them are planar.

Comment: Following on from the above comment, the complete graph on 5 vertices is a counter-example. See the Wikipedia article on planar graphs for example.

Comment: The question about extra conditions is terribly open-ended. Surely a graph with signature $\underbrace{2,2,\ldots,2}_n$ is planar as it is one big cycle, for example. Less trivial answers are surely possible too.

Comment: Silly of me; as pointed out, a complete graph with 5 vertices is an obvious counterexample, so I'll take NO for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ultimate criterion for planar graphs is [Wagner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%27s_theorem), which roughly says that a graph is planar whenever it doesn't contain a copy of the complete graph on five vertices nor a copy of the complete bipartite graph on $3+3$ vertices. [The more precise statement is that a graph is planar whenever it has neither of these two graphs as a [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor).] Neither of these two small graphs is planar, and the theorem basically says that if a graph doesn't have these small local reasons not to be planar than the graph itself is planar.

Notice this has very little to do with the degrees of the vertices. So for example, complete graphs on $2n+1$ vertices with $n\ge2$, or bipartite graphs on $(2m)+(2n)$ vertices with $m,n\ge2$, are even yet not planar.

Comment: Your statement of Wagner's theorem is **much** too rough; you are reinforcing a common misunderstanding of the theorem among undergraduate students.

Answer (score 3):

K5 is not planar but every vertex has 4 edges on it.